# How can i count a value in all of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count an specific value in all of the data frame. 
for example, we have a data frame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0 : ["a", "b", "a"],
    1 : ["c", "a", "b"],
    2 : ["c", "b", "b"]
})
```

```py
>>> df
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | c | c |
| 1 | b | a | b |
| 2 | a | b | b |

I want this result :

```
a 3
b 4
c 2
```

any body know, how can i do it ?!
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
b    4
a    3
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `value_counts` method, but use `stack` before calling this method.

```
df.stack().value_counts()
>>>
b    4
a    3
c    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Different answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0 : ["a", "b", "a"],
    1 : ["c", "a", "b"],
    2 : ["c", "b", "b"]
})
df1 = pd.melt(df, value_vars=[0,1,2],var_name='colName',value_name='value').groupby('value').count()
print(df1)



colName value         
a            3
b            4
c            2
```